# rails3 routes how to match root `/` to path homes#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

i tried to use the resources :homes can work,but then second line code didn't work

```
resources :homes #right
root :to => 'homes#index'#didn't work
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Is that everything you have in your `routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `root :to => 'homes#index'` at the end of your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: in fact is i delete the index.html in public directory ,then everything work fine